# If $g(x)=(x+2\sqrt x)e^x$, find $g'(x)$

Tags: derivatives

> If $g(x)=(x+2\sqrt x)e^x$, find $g'(x)$

I did this math and I found $$g'(x) = (1 + x^{-1/2})e^x$$

But my friend is saying my answer is wrong. The correct answer is $$e^x[x+2x^{1/2}+ 1 + x^{-1/2}]$$

Can u please tell which one is the correct answer and if I'm wrong why?

Comment: I have edited your answer, please check that I didn't misinterpret something.

Comment: no that was good thanks. But how did u do it?

Comment: You can click "edit" to see what I have changed. For reference on how to use LaTeX formatting, have a look at this: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

You have a product of two function therefor you need to use this formula $$(u\cdot v)' = u'v+uv'$$

where $u =x+2\sqrt{x}$ and $v = e^x$.

Answer (score 1):

Your friend is right as he's applied product rule appropriately.

Think of $f(x) = e^x$ and $h(x) = x + 2\sqrt x$.

$g(x) = f(x) h(x) $

Can you apply product rule now?

Comment: ya thanks, I get it now

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{split}
\frac{d}{dx} &\left[\left(1+x^{-1.2}\right)e^x\right] \quad \text{by Product Rule}\\
&= e^x \frac{d}{dx}\left[1+x^{-1.2}\right] + \left(1+x^{-1.2}\right) \frac{d}{dx} \left[e^x\right] \\
&= e^x \left(1-1.2x^{-2.2}\right) + \left(1+x^{-1.2}\right)e^x
\end{split}
$$
can you simplify the result?

Comment: ya, I get it now thanks